# Why isn't the Type class in the System.Reflection namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, design-decisions

Everything about `Type` is reflective in nature. Is it because `Type` is used more often than the rest of the classes in `System.Reflection`? Or because it functions more like a system class than a reflection class?

In short, I've always wondered what the motivation behind the location of `System.Type` was.

Comment: It could be because it's the mechanism of reflection. It's like your eyes. You will never actually see your eyes. You'll only, at best, see the reflection of your eyes.

Comment: Sure, the eyes are a mechanism to see one's own reflection. Though the comment only strengthens the question. Since you can't directly see your own eyes (i.e. can't directly see type info), you need some kind of reflection to get any information (i.e. `Type`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Type class is used in a lot more places, not just System.Reflection.  A quick search with Reflector reveals hundreds of them.  It is crucial in System.Configuration, System.Data,  System.Drawing, System.Linq, System.Windows.Forms, etc.  The way the Type instance is actually used in these classes isn't visible.  It is likely that System.Reflection is used but that's an implementation detail that in no way affects the program.

Given that creating the Type instance that these classes need is trivial with the typeof operator and object.GetType and that you never have to use System.Reflection unless you actually write reflection code, Type certainly deserves an easily accessible location in the System namespace.

Answer (score 1):

An assembly has types and `Assembly` lies on `System.Reflection` which is curious.

So my guess would be that it has something to do with `Object` implementing the method `GetType` which returns a `Type`.

Comment: Incidentally, `Object.getClass` in Java parallels this.

Comment: Though by the same logic, shouldn't `MemberInfo` be in the `System` namespace as well? `Type` implements `GetMember()` which returns a `MemberInfo`. Forward-referencing of namespaces happens all over the place within the BCL.

Comment: @Arc, indeed, but the use case `Object.GetType()` is much more frequently used than `Object.GetType().GetMember()`.

Comment: Very true, though if `Type` is in `System.Reflection` you could still do `o.GetType.FullName` without needing any extra using  blocks. Using `Type` for anything else usually requires `using System.Reflection` even when it's located in `System`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because Object as a GetType method.

MS coding practicing tell that  a class should not reference a type in a subnamespace. In practice, the BCL violates this rule quite often ;o)